# Why there is no java.nio.ByteBuffer in the source code of Openjdk1.8?

Tags: nio, java

Recently I was reading the source code of OpenJDK1.8 and have a question about the source code. The question as below. Anyone can help?

The **ByteBuffer** class exists below the package **java.nio** in Oracle Java1.8, but I found there is no such class in [the same package of OpenJDK1.8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/share/classes/java/nio). I downloaded the source code of OpenJDK1.8 from [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src).

Comment: What about http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/nio/ByteBuffer.java#ByteBuffer

Comment: It looks like some code generation is in use: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/share/classes/java/nio/ByteBufferAs-X-Buffer.java.template

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @erickson Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The source files with the `.template` suffix are processed in the JDK build to generate the classes at build time. For example, ByteBuffer (along with all IntBuffer, LongBuffer, ...) are generated from X-Buffer.java.template. If you have your own build then look in the `gensrc` tree in the output directory to see the generated classes.